# Rewriting multiple LIKEs in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL I can rewrite multiple equivalencies like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (name = "a" or name = "b")
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name in ("a", "b")
```

Is there a way to do the same with a `%LIKE%` statement? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (name like "a%" or name like "b%")
```

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like ("a%", "b%")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
where name regexp '^[ab]'
```

Comment: thanks for this, does `regexp` still use an index (if it can) ?

Comment: @David542 . . . No.  Indexes are tricky in this case.  You could use instead `name >= 'a' and name < 'c'`.

Comment: ah, ok thanks for that clarification. Are there any docs on the use (or non-use) of indexes with regexes and such?

Comment: @David542 . . . That is simple.  I'm pretty sure `regexp` never uses an index, even for constant expressions (although conceivably MySQL could have an optimization there).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.  But be aware queries with "like" are quite heavy if database is big. Try not to use them in future.

SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE field_name LIKE '%a'
   OR field_name LIKE 'b%'
   OR field_name LIKE 'three[abv]'

Comment: `a%` could use an index though, no?

Comment: Yes u can. Here is an article for indexing like queries  https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: thanks for sharing, but not quite sure how that's relevant, as it talks about queries in the form of `te%m`, and it says `LIKE filters can only use the characters before the first wild card during tree traversal.`.